# What type of View I can use for text+images report?

Tags: iphone

I want to make some sort of **non-editable** "report" view with images, titles and text in it. 
Images generates in code, not from bandle, so I can't use UIWebView.

User puts some data into previous view and press "done" - Next view opens with

```
"generated image 
 some text 
 title
 mini title
 image
 text ... " etc
```

I think its similar to custom UITableView + UITextView. 
Has anyone other suggestions?

UPD View is dynamic (not fixed) - text and images generates from code. "report" can be different length from time to time. User can scroll this "report". It's like Help screen in some applications - rich-format text with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Interface Builder to build a custom UIView. Then you can put UIImageView, UITextView. This can only be done if your view is fixed, isn't it?

Comment: my view is not fixed - its dynamic and depends on user parameters
it can be 10 mini-texts long or 15 or 20 etc...

Comment: Then you can use [view addSubview:], and initialize your view at runtime. A UITableView is also good but I am not sure if you can put it half screen

Comment: hmmm... I dont mentioned half screen ) see my update
UPD View is dynamic (not fixed) - text and images generates from code. "report" can be different length from time to time. User can scroll this "report". It's like Help screen in some applications - rich-format text with images.

Comment: Take a look at Three20, it is one of big library people use when they start to do something advanced UI http://three20.info/overview#UI